# jSoup to get text from <td><span> class

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have a part of html file with below format

```
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">20,000</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">19,500</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1"><span><span>19,000</span></span> - <span><span>19,600</span></span></td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1"><span>18,000</span> - <span>26,000</span></td>
```

there are other span classes. But I would like to get below 3 value only, which will be inserted into the database.

19,500

19,000

19,600

I have tried:

```
Elements elements = doc.select(".yfnc_tabledata1");
            for(Element e : elements) {
                System.out.println(e.text());                                           
            }
```

and even i tried

```
doc.select(".yfnc_tabledata1").select("span");
```

still doesn't work, please kindly help.

Comment: have you checked if the document is empty

Comment: How are we supposed to get only those three values? You have four different values with exactly the same attributes.

Comment: Can you try: `doc.select("td.yfnc_tabledata1");`

Comment: Do you have the td's in a table?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to parse only a part of html in order to select the td tags you have at least to add a table and tr tag at the begining. Example :

```
public class NewClass7 {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
String html = "<table>\n" +
                "<tr>" + 
                "<td class=\"yfnc_tabledata1\">20,000</td>\n" +
                "<td class=\"yfnc_tabledata1\">19,500</td>\n" +
                "<td class=\"yfnc_tabledata1\"><span><span>19,000</span></span> - <span><span>19,600</span></span></td>\n" +
                "<td class=\"yfnc_tabledata1\"><span>18,000</span> - <span>26,000</span></td>";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements tds = document.select("td");
        for (Element e : tds) {
            if(e.text().startsWith("19"))
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
}
```

}